# How to mock a system class for type casting

Tags: android, junit, mockito, android-testing, mockito-kotlin

I have the following code to get the current system memory:

```
val memClass = (context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).memoryClass
```

My initial goal is to return an `Int` value for it in testing. Something like this:

```
whenever((context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).memoryClass)
.thenReturn(500)
```

Since its a jUnit test and involves using the `Context`, I ended up mocking everything:

```
val context: Context = mock()

val activityService: Service = mock()

whenever(context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .thenReturn(activityService)

whenever((context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).memoryClass)
            .thenReturn(500)
```

Now the problem is `Mockito` can't create a typecast for `ActivityManager` and throwing this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Service$MockitoMock$594525704 cannot be cast to android.app.ActivityManager
```

I also tried mocking the ActivityManager but it can't be used as a typecast:

[image]

I don't have a specific requirement to stick with the current solution. I will appreciate a better approach to my initial goal.

Comment: why not `val activityService: ActivityManager = mock()` ?

Comment: @second Yes, but then I can't use ```(context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as activityService```. I need to use ```.... as ActivityManager``` instead of ```as activityService``` The ```as``` keyword is responsible for casting the while line to a type of  ```ActivityManager```

Comment: I see neither the `(context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as activityService` nor the `while line`in your question, or am I missing something?

Comment: @second Sorry, I made a typo it should be "The ```as``` keyword is responsible for casting the whole line to a type of ActivityManager". Please check the updated question. I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: why don`t you cast to a class, but the variable? Unless thats another typo.

Comment: @second Casting the ```ActivityManager``` class throws an error  ```java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Service$MockitoMock$594525704 cannot be cast to android.app.ActivityManager``` because the ```ActivityManager``` isn't mocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe we have a misunderstanding. What I am talking about was this:

```
val context: Context = mock()

val activityService: ActivityManager = mock()

whenever(context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .thenReturn(activityService)

whenever((context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).memoryClass)
            .thenReturn(500)
```

As far as I understand:
context.getSystemService( ... ) returns an Object.

There is no relation between the classes android.app.ActivityManager and android.app.Service.

---

Edit:
The last line might need to be replaced with the equivalent of
            (the given code is probably not be the correct kotlin syntax)

```
    when(activityService.memoryClass).thenReturn(500);
```

Comment: Wow, that was a silly mistake I had to use ```val activityService: ActivityManager``` instead of ```val activityService: Service = mock()```. Thanks a lot. Tested and working as expected.